# Print document from word template on both sides of the paper

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, templates

I have a word template that is one page long. It is used for letters. Now if I create a letter of more than one page - let's say 3 pages - and try to print it such that both sides of the paper are used, word prints the *first* page on its own and then prints the 2nd and 3rd page on the same piece of paper. If I print a two-sided letter word just prints each page on one piece of paper. If I don't use the template, double sided printing works just fine.

I googled around for someone with a similar problem but I couldn't find anything similar. Do you have any ideas?

EDIT: I found the problem. The first page was set to come from a different paper source than the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Do your printer driver options include a page order setting (see below)? See what happens when you reverse this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Has the second page been set to print on the left hand page?. See "Layout", "Section Start" "Odd Page"